# Create Outlook 2007 Search Folder for people outside of my organization

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search, exchange

I'd like to create a Search Folder in Outlook that only contains mails from people outside of my company. It's a Mailbox on an Exchange server, and my naive approach was "'From' 'doesn't contain' '@mycompany.com'", but that doesn't work, it looks like it's only matching the Display Name.

Is there a way to filter this to only have external mail shown in a Search Folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Scott Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheThreeMostImportantOutlookRulesForProcessingMail.aspx), specifically the section on "Processing External Mail with an Outlook Rule".  While he's using rules to filter to a folder, you can do something similar.  Either translate it directly to a search filter, or use the rule to apply a category to the email and then search off the category.

Comment: Please can you include the key parts of that link in this answer. If the link breaks, this answer is worthless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever found an answer for this issue but I did.

Here's the direct link to the blog article I found.  It has to do with exposing an e-mail property and sorting/filtering by that.  I hope this helps you or someone else.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ewan/archive/2007/01/09/using-outlook-search-folders-to-filter-only-external-mail.aspx